# Render the form fileds into panel_widget by symfony and twig and bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I use stack from the next frameworks:

1. Symfony 3.0.6
2. Twig bridge 3.0
3. Bootstrap 3

I try to make my own class to rendering form into bootstrap [panels](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels) and I used [the example](https://gist.github.com/spcmky/8512371) as a base

I made the next files

### a class for describing the panels as the objects

```php
<?php  
namespace AppBundle\FormFields;


use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BaseType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;

class Panel extends BaseType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions (OptionsResolver $resolver){
        $resolver -> setDefaults([
            'title' => false,
            'elements' => array(),
            'options' => array(),
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if (!empty($options['elements'])){
            foreach ($options['elements'] as $element) {
                $builder->add($element['id'],$element['type'],$element['attr']);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        if(isset($options['title']) || $options['title'] !== false) {
            $view -> vars['title'] = $options['title'];
        }
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix(){
        return 'panel';
    }
}
```

### the twig file

```php
{% block panel_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default(' ')  ~ ' panel panel-default' )|trim}) %}
        <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
            {% if title is defined %}
                <div class="panel-heading">
                        {{ title }}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="panel-body">
                {{ form_widget(form) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock panel_widget %}
```

### and the controller for making and rendering form

```php
->add('test', new Panel(), [
            'title' => 'тестовая проверка',
            'required' => false,
            'elements' => [
                'name'=>'username',
                'type'=>'text',
                'attr'=> array(
                    'required' => true
                ),
            ],
        ])
```

But I watch the error message from Symfony
[image: the error message from Symfony]
But I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, I answer myself to my question :)

At first, I changed my class

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\FormFields;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;

//Extended class was changed
class Panel extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions (OptionsResolver $resolver){
        $resolver -> setDefaults([
            'title' => false,
            'elements' => array(),
            'options' => array(),
        ]);
        $resolver->setRequired('elements');
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if (!empty($options['elements'])){
            foreach ($options['elements'] as $element) {
                /*
                 * The principle of getting the element data was changed
                 */
                $builder->add($element[0],$element[1],$element[2]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        if(isset($options['title']) || $options['title'] !== false) {
            $view -> vars['title'] = $options['title'];
        }
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'panel';
    }
}
```

Then I changed the algorithm of making the elements.

```
->add('test',Panel::class,[
    'title' => 'test title',
    'attr' => [
        'type' => 'info',
    ],
    'elements' => [
        ['FName',TextType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'Your name',
                'required' => false,
            ]
        ],
        ['some_choise',ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => [
                'one' => '1',
                'two' => '2',
            ],
            ]
        ],
        ['toSend',ButtonType::class, [
            'label'=>'Find',
            'attr' => [
                'last' => true,
                ],
            ]
        ],
    ],
])
```

And I've changed the twig widget

```
{% block panel_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% set type = attr.type|default('default') %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({class: ('panel panel-' ~ type ~ ' ' ~ attr.class|default(''))|trim}) %}
        <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
            {#{% if title is defined %}#}
            {% if title | length > 0 %}
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    {#<h3 class="panel-title">#}
                        {{ title }}
                    {#</h3>#}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="panel-body">
                {{ form_widget(form) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock panel_widget %}

{% block bootstrap_panel_label %}
{% endblock bootstrap_panel_label %}
```

Of course, you can use it :)
Enjoy it.

P.S.
Don't forger to say thanks ;)